# Checking ModelState in ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Here is the POST action in my `ApiController`.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(ViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var ResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.XXXXXX
            return ResponseMessage; 
        }

        if (!_service.Create(model))
        {
            var ResponseMessage=new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
            return ResponseMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
    }
```

Is it okay to enable server-side model validation in this way? And, I am pretty sure a `Created` should be returned if everything is fine. But what kind of HttpStatusCode should I return if the ModelState is invalid, or if some error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it should be 400 - `BadRequest`.

`NotAcceptable` is when Accept headers cannot be satisfied by the server.

`PreConditionFailed` is when caching validation conditions fails. For example, if a PUT request requires update if and only if ETag match value in the request.

---

Alternatively you may send custom error. Since it is to do with Request, you need to use 4xx numbers:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode) 499) 
     {
          ReasonPhrase = "Validation failed"
     };
```

Comment: Is there a way we can distinguish between invalid input (`ModelState.IsValid==false`) and other error?

Comment: @Blaise What error? If error is at server then it will be 500-series error. 400 is when the request is not valid. If you specify exactly what other error I could help.

Comment: Thanks. I will return a 400 when Model is invalid and return a 500 when the workerservice fails (indicating it is a server error other than invalid model).

Comment: @Blaise yes. ALthough when I said 500 I meant 5xx. Have a look at HTTP spec: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Wow! ReasonPhrase. I like that. Thank you.